# Using scrape functions (Rvest) to download files using html_form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm working with certain data sets from the following url (the page is in spanish): http://www.aire.cdmx.gob.mx/default.php?opc=%27aKBh%27

On the website, you can select the year you want and then click download to get the xls file.

I want to automate the process in order to extract the data sets from 2001 up to 2020, but the only solution (especially for the "download" button - 'Descargar archivo') that I can think of is using the `html_form()` function from `Rvest`, something like this:

```
url = "http://www.aire.cdmx.gob.mx/default.php?opc=%27aKBh%27"
search = read_html(url)
form = html_form(search)[[1]]
fill = form %>%
    html_form_set(seluniano = "2001")

##The filled form looks like this:

> fill
<form> '<unnamed>' (POST )
  <field> (select) seluniano: 2001
  <field> (submit) unibaja: Descargar archivo
>
```

I know some of the problems this arises: If I use the `html_form_submit()`, I get the error:

```
Error: `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute
```

And then, if I get that function to work, how can I download the file?

I think this isn't the best aproach, but that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: That form doesn't doesn't use "normal" web techniques of submitting a form, it uses javascript to submit the form. `rvest` cannot execute javascript. You generally need a web browser for that. You can use something like RSelenium instead to run the javascript, or you can reverse engineer the javascript to see what it actually does when you click the button.

Comment: You won't be able to use rvest to submit this form and download the data because the query is built and submitted using javascript.  But the directories where the data are hosted are public facing so you can scrape these pages for the links and download easily enough - the format is `http://datosabiertos.aire.cdmx.gob.mx:8080/opendata/excel/RAMA/` / `http://datosabiertos.aire.cdmx.gob.mx:8080/opendata/excel/REDMET/` etc.

Comment: Well, now I know where to go from here. Thank you both!

Comment: Update: With the links that @27ϕ9 posted, now I can scrape using Rvest. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @BrunoDamianAguirredelVilla where did 27ϕ9  posted the links?